# create a select with the date of the saturdays in the next 4 months 

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, calendar

Ho to all.
I was wondering how can I create a select with the date of the saturdays in the next four months, using jquery.ui as a reference for the date.
I just wanna create something like that:

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="July">
    <option value="30/07/2012">30</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="August">
    <option value="04/08/2012">4</option>
    <option value="11/08/2012">11</option>
    <option value="18/08/2012">18</option>
    <option value="25/08/2012">25</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

...

Any help will be strongly appreciated.

Thank you so much for the attention.

Comment: You should've atleast posted that confused stuff to fix it

Comment: Have you tried using the built in Date function? I'd recommend using it, as date calculations can get tricky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as you start doing any sort of date math, you should always evaluate the leading date libraries out there. jQUeryUI's date functionality is centered around the needs of the datepicker and, while awesome, if you don't need the actual date picker then you may be better off using something like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

To find the next several saturdays with Moment, you can do something like:

```
var thisSaturday = moment().day(6); // 6th day of the week = saturday

var num = 4,
    upcomingSaturdays = [
      thisSaturday
    ];

for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
  upcomingSaturdays.push(moment(thisSaturday).add('days', 7 * i));
}

document.write(upcomingSaturdays.join('<br>'));
```

​

And [on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/658yL/)

Comment: ps, the document.write is for visual use only in JSFiddle. Obviously don't use document.write in production code

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice, jsoverson, I used moment.js and it works like a charm.
Please, vote for my question if you believe.

Answer (score 0):

This is my final code, thanks to jsoverson, I hope it will be helpful for someone else:

```
var thisSaturday = moment().day(6); // 6th day of the week = saturday
var num = 16,
    upcomingSaturdays = [
      thisSaturday
    ];
for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
  upcomingSaturdays.push(moment(thisSaturday).add('days', 7 * i).format("DD/MM/YYYY"));
}
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("select#date").html(upcomingSaturdays.join('<option>'));
});
```